# How to pass custom parameters in header request

Tags: angular

I have to call an API, I need to pass username and password along with header request. How to call API from angular service?

I tried with this code:

```
    checkUserApi(url: string): Observable<any> {    
       const headers = new HttpHeaders()      
           .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
           .set('Accept', 'text/plain')
          .set('userName', 'username')
         .set('password', 'password');                    
    return this.http.post(url, { headers })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log("response : " +response);
        return response;
      })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the $resource .login method compute the header string at method invocation time, the header configuration needs to have a header property with a value which is a function declaration, not a function invocation.

```
 //resources
var Authentication = $resource('/users/authentication',{},{
    login:{
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false,
        //USE function declaration
        headers: {
           'Authentication': 
                function () {
                    return btoa(getUserCredentials())
                }
        }
        //NOT function invocation
        //headers: {'Authentication':btoa(getUserCredentials())}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,

```
checkUserApi(url: string): Observable<any> {    
    const config = { headers:  {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'text/plain',
        "X-userName": "testUser",
        "X-password": "testPwd"
    }
  };
 return this.http.post(url, config)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log("response : " +response);
        return response;
      });
}
```

Comment: getting error in console like :POST 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: try - return this.http.post(url, {}, config)  // no body for post? if then why to make post call?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out:

```
 let tHeader = new Headers();
 tHeader.append('x-username', UserName);
 tHeader.append('x-password', Password);
 return this.http.post(url,{payload}, { headers: tHeaders })
  .map((response: Response) => {
    console.log("response : " +response);
    return response;
  });
```

this.http.post(url, { headers }) ---> this is not the right way of passing header. Please go through the above code.

In every post request , you should pass a payload. If you dont have any payload to send, pass an empty object.

Comment: getting error like Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with

Comment: so your back end needs some kind of customer header right? if then you need change the name of your custom header to what your backend accepts.